# I Can't access Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

[image: i can't access eclipse marketplace , i tried to configure the proxy server but it didn't work]

I can't access https://marketplace.eclipse.org/ too

any help with this issue??

Comment: http://www.troubleshootyourself.com/cannot-open-eclipse-marketplace/

Comment: @ KDeogharkar i tried this didn't work .since the link is not accessible i think the problem shouldn't be related to the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Trying this link in a normal browser:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subversive-svn-team-provider

(It is a random link from the marketplace)... I think all the MarketPlace is currently down! :-(

Regards,

WovW

Comment: SO isn't a place for spreading status information of other services